# Equivalent of docker -it flag in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to write the equivalent of the following in docker-compose.yaml.

How can I do that?

```
docker run -it myImage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have 2 flags:

- i - Keep STDIN open even if not attached
- t - Allocate a pseudo-TTY

So we just need to find the right keys to put in docker-compose.yaml ([tty](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#tty) & [stdin_open](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#stdin_open))

```
version: "3.9" #you can put you own version
services:
  yourServiceName:
    image: yourImageName
    tty: true               # equivalent for -t
    stdin_open: true        # equivalent for -i
```

Now you can use docker-compose up to run your container (or docker-compose start if you already have a created container)

More info about other flags ([LINK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/))